# html session timeout in progress bar

Tags: javascript, html

I am facing some difficulties while get the proper code to show the session timeout count down in the progress bar in my html page.

Can any one help me in doing this.

Thanks

Comment: Status bar?  I didn't think browsers let you write to the status bar anymore.

Comment: Haven't even seen a status bar in a browser in such a long time forgot they even existed! I'm guessing only IE still has it.

Comment: It is there....If you have searched you will find some images that it is showing...so what is the best way to display session time out for the user?

Comment: @user1080320: Display it on the page somewhere.

Comment: What is the best practise? And what is the appropriate code? The session time out will be 30 minutes and I need to show count down

Comment: usually the countdown timer indicating `minutes:seconds` appear near log out button area but it is up to designer I guess

Answer (score 0):

I searched over internet and found [one example](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/124500/session-time-out-in-php) on how can be this done. Here is one simple example - `$inactive` variable is session expiracy time, e.g. `600` seconds):

```js
function start_onload(){
    var expire_time = new Date().getTime() + 1000*<?php echo $inactive; ?>;
    countdown_session_timeout();
    function countdown_session_timeout() {
        var current_time = new Date().getTime();
        var remaining = Math.floor((expire_time - current_time)/1000);
        var timeout_message = document.getElementById('timeout_message');
        if (remaining>0) {
            timeout_message.innerHTML = 'Session will expire in '+ Math.floor(remaining/60) + ' min. ' + (remaining%60) + ' sec.';
            setTimeout(countdown_session_timeout, 1000);
        } else {
            timeout_message.innerHTML = 'Session expired.';
        }
}
```

}

Php script here: http://pastebin.com/Dik0hyYd  (those sessions are only as example.)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I would like jsp example

Comment: Hi, I don't know jsp so probably I won't help you. Googled a bit for it, probably you need only to replace in the script above: `<?php echo $inactive; ?>` with `<%=inactive%>` . It is just a number of seconds until the session will expire.

Comment: I am sorry, I dunno how to handle sessions in JSP. You should Edit your question and add the JSP tag there.